# Change the number format in the input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, cleave

I want to change the number format with (`,`) in thousands, for example 2000 to 2,000 20000 to 20,000 and so on.
I have tried to browse and I found a suitable library that is cleave.js, 
but there is one problem in this library which is that I can only recognize one selector, while there are lots of input texts that I want to change, does anyone have another solution?

```
var cleave = new Cleave('.loan_max_amount', {
    numeral: true,
    numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'
});
```

Comment: can you give me, example code?

Comment: What do you mean, one selector? `'.loan_max_amount'` will target all inputs that have the `loan_max_amount` class, there can be as many as you want

Comment: @Newbie123 added the answer kindly check, no need to have a library to show to the ui

Comment: yes one selector will select all the classes that exist, and change it to the format that I want

Comment: You can select the elements using document.querySelectorAll(), loop through it and format the value for each selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only apply a cleave instance to one element at a time:

> .input-element here is a unique DOM element. If you want to apply
>   Cleave for multiple elements, you need to give different CSS selectors
>   and apply to each of them, effectively, you might want to create
>   individual instance by a loop
>
> - [Cleave Documentation](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js/)

Following this advice, you can achieve this by using [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to loop over all elements with your class and apply a cleave instance to each element like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.loan_max_amount').forEach(inp => new Cleave(inp, {
  numeral: true,
  numeralThousandsGroupStyle: 'thousand'
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cleave.js@1.5.3/dist/cleave.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="loan_max_amount" />
<input type="text" class="loan_max_amount" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intl.NumberFormat`

```js
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number));
// expected output: "￥123,457"

// limit to three significant digits
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number));
// expected output: "1,23,000"
```

It's not from [cleave.js](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js/) but you can find it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Answer (score 0):

you can use [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Sample snippet

```js
var n = 34523453.345
let seperated = n.toLocaleString()
console.log(seperated)
```

The problem in this one is basically return is a string, or you can check this library [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) might be interesting.

Or as David Japan Suggested you can use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Sample snippet

```js
let number = 123000
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number));
```

Comment: Doesn't better `new Intl.NumberFormat` ?

Comment: Yes me too ! I didn't know toLocaleString is working like this before :> Thz.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
//jQuery
$(".test").on('keyup', function(){
    var n = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''),10);
    $(this).val(n.toLocaleString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="test" id="formattedNumberField" value="" />
<input type="text" class="test" id="formattedNumberField1" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add library for this, you can achieve it with simple regex.This also works for decimal numbers.

```
const formatNumber = (num)=> {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
}
```

Comment: `Intl.NumberFormat` e.g isn't a library. It's also a object like `new RegExp()`